# Unable to access the checkbox for Serverside coding

Tags: asp.net

Below is my gridview ,

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridview1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server" 
         EnableModelValidation="True" >
      <Columns>
      <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Link" HeaderText="Delete"  InsertImageUrl="~/_layouts/images/TBS.WebParts/Button-Delete-icon.png" ShowDeleteButton="true"/>
<asp:BoundField HeaderText ="Size" DataField="FileSize" />
<asp:BoundField HeaderText ="File" DataField="Size" />
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SupportIncluded">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="Checkbox1" runat="server" Checked="false" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Now on server side i want to check if the checkbox is checked or not on Submit button click event.

```
 private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsValidPost())
        {
            bool flag = false;
            for( int i=0; i < gridview1.Rows.Count ; i++)
            {
                if(dgdUpload.Rows[i].FindControl("Checkbox1"),CheckBox).Checked) erorr here...I also tried ....if(Checkbox1.checked)...but unable to access Checkbox1..it says it does not exist in the current context....


                flag = true;
            }
            if(flag)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to access not only the row but also the template field control. Another option is to develop your own recursive version of FindControl that does a search on the whole tree and not just on one level.

Something like:

```
dgdUpload.Rows[i].Controls[5].FindControl("Checkbox1")
```

if I counted the columns in your gridview correctly 5 should be the index of the template field.

Comment: Isn't it a zero based index? 
CommandField - 0 | BoundField 1 | BoundField 2 | TemplateField 3